# Can't link a project using cmake with OpenCV and LibTorch

Tags: opencv, cmake, libtorch

I asked a similar question about linking a project with OpenCV a few days ago.  I got that working, but now I've hit a very weird problem using CMake and adding LibTorch to the project.

If I only use OpenCV in the project, everything compiles, links, and runs fine.

But if I add Torch to CMakeLists.txt, I get a linker error:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0 FATAL_ERROR)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
project(torchscriptie)

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

find_package(Torch HINTS "/usr/local/libtorch")
message(STATUS "TORCH_LIBRARIES = ${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${TORCH_CXX_FLAGS}")

add_executable(torchscriptie main.cpp)
target_link_libraries( torchscriptie ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
target_link_libraries(torchscriptie "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")
set_property(TARGET torchscriptie PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)
```

This CMakeLists.txt file causes this error:

```
CMakeFiles/torchscriptie.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
/code/cpp/torchscriptie/main.cpp:18: undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'
/code/cpp/torchscriptie/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(std::string const&, int)'
/code/cpp/torchscriptie/main.cpp:25: undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here's the command:

```
/usr/bin/c++  -g  -rdynamic CMakeFiles/torchscriptie.dir/main.cpp.o  -o torchscriptie  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/libtorch/lib /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gapi.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_alphamat.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_aruco.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_bgsegm.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_bioinspired.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ccalib.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dnn_objdetect.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dnn_superres.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dpm.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_face.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_freetype.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_fuzzy.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_hdf.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_hfs.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_img_hash.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_intensity_transform.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_line_descriptor.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_quality.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_rapid.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_reg.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_rgbd.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_saliency.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stereo.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_structured_light.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_surface_matching.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_tracking.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_viz.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_xobjdetect.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_xphoto.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/libtorch/lib/libtorch.so /usr/local/libtorch/lib/libc10.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_shape.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_datasets.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_plot.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_text.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dnn.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_phase_unwrapping.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_optflow.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ximgproc.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.4.3.0 -Wl,--no-as-needed,/usr/local/libtorch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so -Wl,--as-needed /usr/local/libtorch/lib/libc10.so -lpthread -Wl,--no-as-needed,/usr/local/libtorch/lib/libtorch.so -Wl,--as-needed
```

I've tried a lot of different combination of commands, but I cannot figure our what's wrong.
When I echo the TORCH_LIBRARIES variable, it returns:

```
torch;torch_library;/usr/local/libtorch/lib/libc10.so
```

If I change the libaries, for example to torch_cpu, I'm able to link OpenCV libraries.

```
set(TORCH_LIBRARIES torch_cpu)
```

I have no idea why Torch libraries are causing link errors with OpenCV in the same project.
Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if this fixes your problem, but I had also a few problems like yours. It is working for me with a cmake file including this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14 FATAL_ERROR)
project(MyProject)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "folderToLibtorch/libtorch/share/cmake")
find_package(Torch REQUIRED)  
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -lm -ldl")
add_executable(MyProject ...some project files...)
target_link_libraries(MyProject ${TORCH_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
set_property(TARGET MyProject PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)
```

So make sure list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "folderToLibtorch/libtorch/share/cmake") is included, this did the trick for me. Also take care to get the right libtorch version from [pytorch](https://pytorch.org/resources/) maybe you should use the lower link and not the "pre-..." version.
Good Luck

[image: Libtorch download]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the version libtorch.
Please  use **libtorch-cxx11-abi-shared-with-deps** not **libtorch-shared-with-deps**. It is library conflict between libtorch and opencv.
Solution  [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/library-conflict-between-libtorch-and-opencv/64489/9).
There is my version of CMakeList.txt with CUDA+LIBTORCH+OPENCV support:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8 FATAL_ERROR)
SET(CUDA_HOME /usr/local/cuda)
SET(CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc)
SET(CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR /usr/local/cuda)
# SET(CUDA_CUBLAS_LIBRARIES /usr/local/cuda/lib64)
SET(CUDA_cublas_device_LIBRARY /usr/local/cuda/lib64)
# SET(CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER_ENV_VAR /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc)
SET(CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS /usr/local/cuda/include)

if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES)
  set(CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES 50)
endif()

set(OpenCV_DIR /usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4)
# set(OpenCV_DIR /usr/local/lib)


project(cmake_and_cuda LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)
 
include(CTest)

find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)

# libtorch with OpenCV support , with fixed  BUG !
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ./libtorch)

find_package(Torch REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "TORCH_LIBRARIES = ${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "OpenCV_LIBS = ${OpenCV_LIBS}")

# ADD OWN CUDA FILES FOR BUILD LIBRARY.
add_library(particles_new_lib STATIC

  torch_module_plus_cuda.cu
  torch_module_plus_cuda.h
  )
  
target_compile_features(particles_new_lib PUBLIC cxx_std_14)
 
# We need to explicitly state that we need all CUDA files in the 
# particles_new_lib library to be built with -dc as the member functions 
# could be called by other libraries and executables
set_target_properties( particles_new_lib
                       PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
 
add_executable(particle_cuda_test torch_and_cuda_call.cpp)
 
set_property(TARGET particle_cuda_test 
             PROPERTY CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)

# LINK ALL LIBRARIES TO TARGET particle_cuda_test
target_link_libraries(particle_cuda_test PRIVATE ${TORCH_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} particles_new_lib)

# LINK LIBRARIES
target_link_libraries(particle_cuda_test PRIVATE particles_new_lib)
set_property(TARGET particle_cuda_test PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)
```